# Resources for data binding with WindowBuilder with SWT/JFace

Tags: java, data-binding, swt, jface, windowbuilder

I just started creating a SWT/JFace application using the (now free) WindowBuilder from Google (previously instantiations).

I find the Data binding part difficult although it -should- make it easier for me.

For instance, I cannot bind the enabling-property of a button to a (myself defined) boolean function.

**Are there any resources (demos, text, tutorials, examples) about using the WindowBuilder GUI and/or the data binding principle?**

The information found on the [google page](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/features/swt/data_binding/index.html) or the [instantiations page](http://download.instantiations.com/D2WBDoc/continuous/latest/docs/html/features/swt/data_binding/index.html) did not help me enough.

Comment: I tried to add a WindowBuilder tag but couldn't do it as I didn't have 1500 reps.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth:

```
bindingContext.bindValue(
    new ComputedValue() {
      public Object calculate() {
        // calculate the enablement using the value of other, previously
        // created observables.
      }
    },
    WidgetProperties.enabled().observe(theButton)
  );
```

The Eclipse newsgroups are a great place to ask these questions.  Try the [eclipse.platform.jface newsgroup](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=15&S=371dbc48cbfd5c88ea6dc964bbc7df36).